# Pandas form groups by closeness of timestamps

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe generated by the following code:

```
l_dates = ['2017-01-01 19:53:36',
           '2017-01-01 19:54:36',
           '2017-01-03 18:15:13',
           '2017-01-03 18:18:11',
           '2017-01-03 18:44:35',
           '2017-01-07 12:50:48']

l_ids = list(range(len(l_dates)))

l_values = [x*1000-1 for x in l_ids]

l_data = list(zip(l_dates, l_ids, l_values))

df1_ = pd.DataFrame(data = l_data, columns = ['timeStamp', 'usageid', 'values'])
```

It looks as follows in this version

```
             timeStamp  usageid  values
0  2017-01-01 19:53:36        0      -1
1  2017-01-01 19:54:36        1     999
2  2017-01-03 18:15:13        2    1999
3  2017-01-03 18:18:11        3    2999
4  2017-01-03 18:44:35        4    3999
5  2017-01-07 12:50:48        5    4999
```

I would like to form groups based on observations that are closely together. For instance, all observations that are within a 15 minute time interval should be grouped together.

I know that I can identify these kinds of observations in a pairwise fashion as follows

```
df_user10241['timeStamp']  < pd.Timedelta(minutes=15)
```

However,  I do not manage to group them s.t. I get a dataframe like the following:

```
             timeStamp  usageid  values   session
0  2017-01-01 19:53:36        0      -1  Session1
1  2017-01-01 19:54:36        1     999  Session1
2  2017-01-03 18:15:13        2    1999  Session2
3  2017-01-03 18:18:11        3    2999  Session2
4  2017-01-03 18:44:35        4    3999  Session3
5  2017-01-07 12:50:48        5    4999  Session4
```

Many thanks in advance and please let me know in case you need further information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `cumsum`

```
'Session'+(df.timeStamp.diff().fillna(0)/np.timedelta64(15, 'm')).gt(1).cumsum().add(1).astype(str)
Out[959]: 
0    Session1
1    Session1
2    Session2
3    Session2
4    Session3
5    Session4
Name: timeStamp, dtype: object
```

After assign it back

```
df['Session']='Session'+(df.timeStamp.diff().fillna(0)/np.timedelta64(15, 'm')).gt(1).cumsum().add(1).astype(str)
df
Out[961]: 
            timeStamp  usageid  values   Session
0 2017-01-01 19:53:36        0      -1  Session1
1 2017-01-01 19:54:36        1     999  Session1
2 2017-01-03 18:15:13        2    1999  Session2
3 2017-01-03 18:18:11        3    2999  Session2
4 2017-01-03 18:44:35        4    3999  Session3
5 2017-01-07 12:50:48        5    4999  Session4
```

Comment: Wow, amazing! Can you explain a bit more. I guess I do not understand `/np.timedelta64(15, 'm')` then `gt(1)` what do these two do?

Comment: @clog14 that is count how many 15 min contain in the timedelta , more than 1(which mean 15 min ) should belong to next group : -)

Comment: OK, thanks I get it know. :-) 
Two more brief questions:
1. I suppose there is no immediate way to do this with a groupby right?
2. If I have a more compex dataframe which has another level say customers, I can pass this solution to a groupby operation on customers, right?

Comment: @clog14 yes, you can group by and pass all above into lambda :-)

Comment: Could anyone please answer the below question, similar to this one, but grouping is not based on closeness. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60965602/pandas-assign-group-numbers-for-each-time-bin